# Complicated select from one table

Tags: sql, count, informix

> ```
> -- I'm trying to create a report for Call Center with quality rating system.
> -- Most of the calls are routed to the queues, where they wait to be answered by agents.
> -- When finishing the call, agent can hangup, requeue the call to another queue
> -- or requeue the call to the Rating queue, where caller may rate (or not)
> -- the quality of service (e.g. 1..5)
> -- There are also cases when calls are not answered, do not reach queue, etc.
> -- Below is a simplified example table. 
> -- Requeued call keeps the same callid, but requeuecount is increased by 1.
> ```
>
> ```
> callid | queue   | agent | rate | requeuecount
> :----- | :------ | :---- | ---: | -----------:
> 122    |         | Olga  | null |           -1
> 123    |         |       | null |           -1
> 124    | Sales   |       | null |            0
> 125    | Service | Tom   | null |            0
> 126    | Sales   | Yan   | null |            0
> 127    | Sales   | Kim   | null |            0
> 127    | Service | John  | null |            1
> 127    | Rating  |       |    4 |            2
> 128    | Service | Oleg  | null |            0
> 128    | Rating  |       | null |            1
> 129    | Service | John  | null |            0
> 130    | Service | John  | null |            0
> 130    | Rating  |       |    2 |            1
> 131    | Sales   | Kim   | null |            0
> 131    | Service | Oleg  | null |            1
> 132    | Service | Oleg  | null |            0
> 132    | Rating  |       |    5 |            1
> ```

> ```
> -- Those only agents who requeued calls to Rating queue.
> -- queue name, agent name, number of calls requeued to Rating, 
> -- number of rated calls, average rating
>
> select cr.queue, cr.agent, count(cr.callid) as req2rating, 
> count(cr1.rate) as ratingscount, avg(cr1.rate) as averagerating
> from callrecord cr
> inner join callrecord cr1 
> on cr.callid=cr1.callid
> and cr.requeuecount=cr1.requeuecount-1
> and cr1.queue='Rating'
> group by cr.queue, cr.agent
> ```
>
> ```
> queue   | agent | req2rating | ratingscount | averagerating
> :------ | :---- | ---------: | -----------: | ------------:
> Service | John  |          2 |            2 |             3
> Service | Oleg  |          2 |            1 |             5
> ```

> ```
> -- All agents with their number of received calls.
> -- queue name, agent name, number of calls he have got
>
> select queue, agent, count(callid) as totalcalls
> from callrecord
> group by queue, agent
> ```
>
> ```
> queue   | agent | totalcalls
> :------ | :---- | ---------:
>         |       |          1
> Rating  |       |          4
> Sales   |       |          1
> Service | John  |          3
> Sales   | Kim   |          2
> Service | Oleg  |          3
>         | Olga  |          1
> Service | Tom   |          1
> Sales   | Yan   |          1
> ```

> ```
> -- I want to combine the two above tables into one.
> -- Straightforward method, that works:
>
> select s1.queue, s1.agent, s1.totalcalls, s2.req2rating, s2.ratingscount, s2.averagerating from
>   (select queue, agent, count(callid) as totalcalls
>   from callrecord
>   group by queue, agent) s1
> left join
>   (select cr.queue, cr.agent, count(cr.callid) as req2rating, 
>   count(cr1.rate) as ratingscount, avg(cr1.rate) as averagerating
>   from callrecord cr
>   inner join callrecord cr1 
>   on cr.callid=cr1.callid
>   and cr.requeuecount=cr1.requeuecount-1 and cr1.queue='Rating'
>   group by cr.queue, cr.agent) s2
> on s1.queue=s2.queue and s1.agent=s2.agent
> ```
>
> ```
> queue   | agent | totalcalls | req2rating | ratingscount | averagerating
> :------ | :---- | ---------: | ---------: | -----------: | ------------:
>         |       |          1 |       null |         null |          null
> Rating  |       |          4 |       null |         null |          null
> Sales   |       |          1 |       null |         null |          null
> Service | John  |          3 |          2 |            2 |             3
> Sales   | Kim   |          2 |       null |         null |          null
> Service | Oleg  |          3 |          2 |            1 |             5
>         | Olga  |          1 |       null |         null |          null
> Service | Tom   |          1 |       null |         null |          null
> Sales   | Yan   |          1 |       null |         null |          null
> ```

> ```
> -- Maybe there is a more clever and efficient way of doing this?
> -- I mean using only one select operand.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a3a7e2b3b0720d3313be0ac4bf7a005)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a select of callrecords-agents and left join on callrecords-ratings in this manner:

```
select cr.queue, cr.agent, count(cr.callid) as totalcalls,
       count(rt.callid) as req2rating,
       count(rt.rate) as ratingscount,
       avg(rt.rate) as averagerating
  from callrecord as cr
  left join callrecord as rt on
            rt.callid = cr.callid and
            rt.queue = 'Rating' and
            rt.requeuecount = cr.requeuecount+1
 group by cr.queue, cr.agent
```

This returns req2rating and ratingscount as 0, if you want null could use the nullif function:

```
select cr.queue, cr.agent, count(cr.callid) as totalcalls,
       nullif(count(rt.callid), 0) as req2rating,
       nullif(count(rt.rate), 0) as ratingscount,
       avg(rt.rate) as averagerating
  from callrecord as cr
  left join callrecord as rt on
            rt.callid = cr.callid and
            rt.queue = 'Rating' and
            rt.requeuecount = cr.requeuecount+1
 group by cr.queue, cr.agent
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroni! This work like a charm.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c72324ba1a67e8541de4a10e3f89b288